# while loop to error check c++?

Tags: c++, while-loop

Can someone please look at this code and help me figure out what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int numExercise;
cout << "Enter num exercises: ";
cin >> numExercise;

vector <float> weight;
float sumWeight = 0;
while(sumWeight != 1)
{   
    // Loop to assign a weighted value to each exercise.
    for ( int i = 0; i < numExercise; i++ )
    {
        float weightEntered;

        cout << "\n Assignment " << i + 1 << " : ";
        cin >> weightEntered;

        //Divide percentage by 100 to get decimals.     
        weightEntered /= 100;

        //Send the data back to the vector.
        weight.push_back( weightEntered );
    }


    // Loop to error check if the total weights isn't 100.

    for ( int i = 0; i < numExercise; i++ )
    {
        sumWeight += weight[i]; 
    }

    cout << sumWeight << endl;
    sumWeight = 0;
    //if ( sumWeight != 1 )

    cout << "\n\t\tError, total weights should be 100" << endl;
}
```

So in this code I'm entering a certain amount of assignments and the weights per assignment have to be over 100%... for example enter 3 assignments and each weight is 30, 30, 40. After the weight is entered the code divides each weight by 100 to get decimal values (I'm using that in the rest of my code to calculate something else).

The issue is that I'm trying to make sure that whatever the user enters add up to 100 otherwise they have to enter the numbers again. When I run this loop and enter the wrong numbers it asks me to enter them again but it doesn't go through the sum of the weights entered the second time, so the number displayed is still the first sum. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: ***please look at this code and help me figure out what's wrong?*** Please learn to use your debugger. In the long run this will help you way more than someone debugging your code for you.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: This code is doomed for failure if the user enters fractional values, such as 10.3, 56.7, etc.  The reason is that you are not guaranteed by any stretch that these numbers will ever exactly equal 1.0 (or 100) when added up, even though you may think they will.  The reason is that floating point is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

You are using vector to store the weights,

Let say for three assignments, you entered 30,30,30. Now vector becomes { 30,30,30 } and you are summing over this vector from 0 to 2 index.
In next time, you entered 20,20,40. Now vector becomes {30,30,30,20,20,40} and you are summing over this vector again from 0 to 2 index.

You can solve your problem by using **insert** rather than **push_back**